# Show that if $φ$ is an isomorphism, then $J$ is a non-zero constant.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $φ : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}^n$ be an regular map, given by polynomials $f_1,...,f_n$ in variables $x_1,...,x_n.$ Let $J$ be the Jacobian polynomial of $φ$, the determinant of the matrix $∂f_i/∂x_j.$

Show that if $φ$ is an isomorphism, then $J$ is a non-zero constant.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: just to be sure -- each f assumes just one value for each vector $x_1,x_2,...x_n$?

Comment: All 3 of your questions are taken word for word from the [first problem set](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/631.2013hmwk1.pdf) of the graduate algebraic geometry course at Michigan...

Answer (score 7):

If $\varphi$ were an isomorphism of algebraic varieties, then it would remain an isomorphism after extending scalars to $\mathbb{C}$.  Also its Jacobian remains the same when viewed over $\mathbb{C}$, but when viewed as a polynomial with complex coefficients, any nonconstant polynomial has a zero.   At a point $P \in \mathbb{C}^n$ where the Jacobian is zero, there is not even a holomorphic inverse function defined locally at the point, so there is certainly no polynomial inverse.

Note that the analytic case really can be different over $\mathbb{R}$: e.g. $f(x) = x^3+x: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has Jacobian (i.e., derivative) $3x^2+1$, which is nonzero for all real $x$.  By the Inverse Function Theorem, $f$ has a smooth inverse $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  It just so happens that $g$ is not a polynomial function (of course; its degree would have to be $\frac{1}{3}$).

**Added**: This problem is related to the notorious [Jacobian Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture).

Also, another answer posted here suggests proceeding by showing that $\varphi$ can only be an isomorphism if $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are linear polynomials.  This is true when $n = 1$ (rather trivially) but false for $n \geq 2$.  Here is an explicit counterexample:

$\varphi(x,y) = (x+(x+y)^3,y-(x+y)^3)$

has Jacobian determinant $1$ and indeed has a polynomial inverse, namely

$\psi(x,y) = (x-(x+y)^3,y+(x+y)^3)$.

Comment: Your insights are very helpful.